# Node js Mongodb findOne not working Synchronously

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a mongodb database with list of users and tokens. When I use query to findOne with query, its returning undefined. The code for findOne is as below:

```
var getApiTokenForUser = function(user){
console.log('get api token for :'+user);
var collection = db.collection(user_token_collection_name);
var result;
if(collection){
    console.log("cursor query: "+user);
    var cursor = collection.findOne({'user':user});
    console.log("cursor result: "+JSON.stringify(cursor));
}
return result;}
```

Logs that i printed for findOne is as below:

```
 get api token for :Zeus
 cursor query: Zeus
 cursor result: {}
 getApiTokenForUser return: undefined
```

But if I use find instead of findOne I can get list of users, but only in logs, it still returns undefined.

code for find is:

```
var getApiTokenForUser = function(user){
console.log('get api token for :'+user);
var collection = db.collection(user_token_collection_name);
var result;
if(collection){
    console.log("cursor query: "+user);
    var cursor = collection.find({'user':user});
    cursor.forEach(function(data) {
        result = data;
        console.log("cursor result: "+JSON.stringify(data));
    });
}
return result;}
```

and logs are:

```
cursor query: Zeus
getApiTokenForUser return: undefined
saveUserApiToken
cursor result: {"_id":"58a56442545e812a68f87bbe","user":"Zeus","token":"eyJhbGci
OiJIUzI1NiJ9.WmV1cw.mAQh65o-d2tOp_Fchi7iPm5pu_2f4QSXOAQ5JtoEe10"}
```

I want findOne to work synchronously. is there any way ?

Comment: Can you show us the context in which `getApiTokenForUser` function gets called? In Node.js, you can't have `findOne` to work in a synchronous manner but you could use `Promises` for this.

Comment: I am using this to validated the user. When user sign in, i am saving the token and user in mongodb and with every rest apis, I am checking with the token is valid or not.

Comment: Firstly do not ever user synchronous word with node.js. Imagine the situation you have 1000 users that are using in real time your site. The fact that you do this call synchronously all the 1000 users will need to wait till the code will executed... Do it asynchronously in this way the rest of 999 users can continue to use your app.

Comment: I agree, but still I am looking for solution to make it synchronous. This server will be used in closed group and that's why we dont expect more that 10 login's at a time.

Answer (score 1):

You never assign result to anything in your first snippet. Your code (simplified):

```
var result; // you never assign anything to it
return result; // undefined
```

Comment: Thanks. corrected. But still its returning empty object, whereas find(), returns list.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to put the synchronous code inside the callback of findOne. For example:

```
collection.findOne({'user':user}, function(error,user) {    
     //Synchornous code here
})
```

Hope my answer was helpful for you.